# How do I run large number of AWS Fargate tasks in parallel through Map state and RunTask API?

Tags: concurrency, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions, rate-limiting

I have a step function with a Map state.

I want to run all map executions in parallel with distributed mode. There would be around 250 executions.

Each Map run will call RunTask to start an AWS Fargate task.

According to [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/throttling.html), RunTask is throttled to 20 calls per second.

But the map state will call all 250 RunTasks at the same time, which causes Rate Limit Exceeded error. Is there any way around this?